# How to make POST request to Rest API?

Tags: angular, laravel, request, httprequest

I spend hours of time to find out how it works. But no luck.
I send a upload with POST request to Laravel, but `formData.append()` in Angular send to RestApi has empty request. Why? This is my Angular Observable:

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file_name', file.name);
```

In Console.log I get file.name and all seems correct.
This is my Post:

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', this.apiUrl, formData, {headers:reqHeader});
```

My header I am sending has content-type:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
```

In laravel request->all() is empty, but why? What is missing that I don`t get data from formData?

Answer (score 1):

You have to append file in form group like this:

`formData.append('file', this.uploadForm.get('file').value);`

and get the value on file upload like this:
`const file = event.target.files[0];`

So, as a complete example try this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-component.scss'],

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    SERVER_URL = "http://YourServerAddress:API_PORT";
    uploadForm: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.uploadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            uploadedFile: ['']
        });
    }

    onFileSelect(event) {
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            this.uploadForm.get('uploadedFile').setValue(file);
        }
    }

    onSubmit() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.uploadForm.get('uploadedFile').value);

        this.httpClient.post < any > (this.SERVER_URL, formData).subscribe(
            (res) => console.log(res),
            (err) => console.log(err)
        );
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div>
    <form [formGroup] = "uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">      
      <div>
        <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" (change)="onFileSelect($event)" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

However it's a sample example to understand the uploading process and in real application it's better to have another service for posting the file to your API.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I checked it out, but get: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Comment: In your `app.module.ts` add this `import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` and in the imports part too like this: `imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],` It will be ok

Answer (score 0):

Try to append file like this;

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file_name', file, file.name);
```

if it's still missing, try $_FILES instead of request->all() with above usage

```
$_FILES['file_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Angular's HttpClient and plain JS object for payload:

```
// ...

constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

// ...

const messageBody = { file_name: file.name };
const req = this.httpClient.post(this.apiUrl, messageBody, { headers:reqHeader });
```